# Cygwin standard console scrollup

Tags: cygwin

Is there a way we can see what we have typed above in a Cygwin console window, since after I type so many things & then when I go up scrolling am not able to go up to where I started, I mean scroll stops after a point, so is there a way we can see until from where we have started typing since login?

I searched on Google & saw we hv to make changes in .Xdefaults file, now where is that file?Also I tried to increase buffer size in Cygwin console window from properties tab, that dint work, checked on this site too,it is suggested here to install mintty or rxvt, so there isn't any way or workaround for this problem for standard Cygwin console other than installing mintty or rxvt?

Answer (score 1):

There are several different terminal programs you could be using with Cygwin.

The default is the Windows command window (the same one used for `cmd.exe`); for that one, setting the screen buffer size in Properties should do the trick.

The `.Xdefaults` file, which should be in `$HOME`, is used for other terminal emulators.  For example, for `xterm` I have `XTerm*saveLines: 1000`.  You could also invoke xterm with the `-sl 1000` command-line option (or whatever value you like).

The `rxvt` terminal emulator is similar, but use `Rxvt*saveLines` rather than `XTerm*saveLines`.

Comment: Thanks..okay so i would install another cygwin terminal, since setting screen buffer size in properties doesn't work....thanks for d help!

Comment: btw..why this questn is transferred from stackoverflow to this site